# Integer Input Fields Using Rails 4 Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, integer

I have added a field to a database that is defined as integer.  I plan to use the field on my as a record count in a controller method.  I have maintenance views that already exist for the database model.  I would like to define an input field on my existing view to input and process the field as an integer.

I took a guess and attempted the following code since text fields are defined as text_field.  However I got an input field with up/down arrows to the right like it was attempting to scroll through a list with nothing to scroll.  The default value appears but grayed out.  Not sure what that means.

```
<%= f.label :broadcasts_in_week, "Broadcasts Per Week:" %>&nbsp;<%= f.number_field :broadcasts_in_week %>
```

I have been searching but could only find this when using simple_form which I'm not using. Everything else I found spoke about how to convert a text to an integer. I want to be able to enter a number in my view and do update_attributes(my_params).

I will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

I continued looking and found a solution. After thinking about this again I realized that I had written my HTML5 code correctly but just needed to change the CSS.  I did not realize that the arrows were called spin buttons.  I added the following CSS code in my stylesheet and get it to look like I wanted to and be able to use my existing controller code to update the integer field.

```
/* hides the spin-button for firefox */
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
    -webkit-appearance:textfield;
    -o-appearance:textfield;
    -khtml-appearance:textfield;
}
/* hides the spin-button for chrome*/
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I also added CSS for the text color and width in another part of my stylesheet.